# Ext.apply cover nested objects?

Tags: object, extjs, merge, extjs4, extjs4.2

I have some configuration objects that I need to copy into another. I **don't care about cloning** the reference but there a deep nested objects within the configuration which need to get merged to. The problem is I do not know which of these configurations exist or how deep they are currently nested. `Ext.apply` is called in a loop and first test show that it seems to override the property of the previous loop.

Can I make `Ext.apply` to run apply on child objects too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the **[API](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/)** for **[Ext.apply](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext-method-apply)** and you will find the answer in the method description

> Copies all the properties of config to the specified object. Note that
>   if recursive merging and cloning without referencing the original
>   objects / arrays is needed, use Ext.Object.merge instead.

I think **[Ext.Object.merge](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.Object-method-merge)** will do what you need

> Merges any number of objects recursively without referencing them or
>   their children.